# Disable expired resharper and restore keybindings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I am waiting on licenses to arrive from licensing team for Resharper I have `suspended` it in `Tools -> Options -> ReSharper`.

However all the key combinations are still bound to ReSharper.

[image]

**How do I completely shut down ReSharper and get my old VS keyboard shortcuts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to `Visual Studio` → `Tools` → `Options` → `Keyboard` and click `Reset`.

The reset button restores Visual Studio's default keyboard commands.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> isn't a default keyboard shortcut, it's added by ReSharper. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - this is what the refactor menu shows for encapsulate field

Comment: The reset button restores Visual Studio's default keyboard commands. Ctrl+R, E isn't a default keyboard shortcut, it's added by ReSharper. Try Ctrl+R, Ctrl+E - this is what the refactor menu shows for encapsulate field.